# Why are my donut sprinkles distorted?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

[image: sprinkles]
I am following the Blender 3.0 Tutorial: [Donut part 9/10](https://youtu.be/4WAxMI1QJMQ).

I created a second mesh to practice on, but the sprinkles look kind of flattened. I don´t know why. I tweaked the Scale Settings in *Instance on Points* to get it right.
On my first try in the back you can see that the sprinkles barely touch the icing.

Comment: Is the donut also distorted? As in did you make a square donut? Or is the original a circle?

Comment: The original is a circle (in the background). The other one is square on intention.

Answer (score 3):

Try applying scale on your sprinkles.

Select the sprinkle objects and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Apply Scale*. If it made a change, then you'll have to tweak the scale values in the *Geometry Nodes* tab to get it right.

If it didn't solve the problem, it's probably because you have weight painted on the down side of the icing.